# Is there a way to cross into Jordan from Israel if I do not have a visa?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, jordan

Let's say I am in Eilat and would like to visit Petra. As a Canadian I need a visa, is there a way to get one on spot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Jordan Pass](http://www.jordanpass.jo/) entitles you to a visa-on-arrival and it also gives you entrance to Petra. You need to print it, though, in my experience electronic copies were not accepted. It is still way less hassle than mailing your passport at home to the consulate.